# piping output of one program into another java windows

Tags: java, cmd

I'm trying the following command

```
java BugSeveritySplitter data.txt | java DataFormatter
```

but the output of BugServeritySplitter doesn't get fed into DataFormatter. BugSeveritySplitter takes a input data file and partitions it into a number of separate files, then outputs the file names using System.out.println(). DataFormater loops through every element in args and formats the data stored in the file of that name. However Dataformatter's standard input is empty.

Comment: everything you said is correct. args and standard input are separate.

Comment: Oh, I thought args was standard input. Thanks.

Comment: you might like the `xargs` command, if you're not in control of these programs

Comment: Nope I am. I just attached a buffered reader to System.in and it worked out. I was just under the assumption that args and System.in were the same thing